# I cannot undelete a question that was deleted by a diamond ♦ moderator

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, vote-to-undelete

I'm trying to undelete a question that was deleted by an elected diamond ♦ moderator. However, when I click "undelete", I get the following popup instead,

> A moderator has deleted this question and it cannot be undeleted

People make mistakes. Moderators are people. Not being able to undo? That's a bug.

Comment: It cannot be undeleted **by you**.

Comment: Yeah - I can't undelete them either:)

Comment: Regarding your question [For the Attention of...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308743/456814), you really ought to stop calling out specific users on Meta, it's usually very poorly received around here.

Comment: Here are some tips on how to write Meta posts that are less likely to be promptly downvoted, closed, and deleted: **(1)** [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188/163250), **(2)** [rants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/rant/info).

Answer (score 36):

Other moderators (and Stack Overflow employees) can undelete.

If warranted.

All such users have a diamond ♦ next to their username.

Comment: "If warranted." Translated: if it really was a mistake.

Comment: E.g., to request a review of the decision, flag the question and say exactly what mistake you think the mod made. (Of course, to do that, you have to be able to see the deleted question, but as the OP said they tried to click "undelete," presumably they can.)

Comment: Single unreviewed moderation deletion is too much authority on a community site.